# Apply CASE WHEN in sqldf statement for manipulating multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, sqldf

I have a dataframe `datwe` with 37 columns. I am interested in converting the integer values(1,2,99) in columns 23 to 35 to character values('Yes','No','NA').

```
datwe$COL23 <- sqldf("SELECT CASE COL23 WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
                                        WHEN 2 THEN 'No'
                                        WHEN 99 THEN 'NA'
                                   ELSE 'Name ittt' 
                              END as newCol
                              FROM datwe")$newCol
```

I have been using the above `sqldf` statements to convert each column separately. I was wondering if there is any other smart way to do this, perhaps apply functions ?

If you require any reproducible data for building dataframe `datwe`, I will add it here. Thanks.

Edit:
Example `datwe`

```
set.seed(12)
data.frame(replicate(37,sample(c(1,2,99),10,rep=TRUE)))
```

Comment: In SQL statement you have 2 whens - `...WHEN WHEN 1...`. Also, why not just extract `col23 - col35`, then convert it to character within R?

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks for that, I have edited the post. I assume that the `as.character()` will convert the integer values to character values. Where should I pass the new values as arguments to convert ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you used `sqldf`, see this example:

```
#dummy data
set.seed(12)
datwe <- data.frame(replicate(37,sample(c(1,2,99),10,rep=TRUE)))

#convert to Yes/No
res <- as.data.frame(
  sapply(datwe[,23:37], function(i)
    ifelse(i==1, "Yes",
           ifelse(i==2, "No",
                  ifelse(i==99,NA,"Name itttt")))))

#update dataframe
datwe <- cbind(datwe[, 1:22],res)

#output, just showing first 2 columns
datwe[,23:24]
#     X23  X24
# 1    No  Yes
# 2   Yes  Yes
# 3   Yes   No
# 4    No   No
# 5   Yes   No
# 6   Yes  Yes
# 7  <NA>   No
# 8    No   No
# 9   Yes <NA>
#10    No <NA>
```

**EDIT:**
Using `sqldf` within a for loop with an external variable:

```
library(sqldf)

#dummy data
set.seed(12)
datwe <- data.frame(replicate(37,sample(c(1,2,99),10,rep=TRUE)))

#sqldf within a loop
for(myCol in paste0("X",23:37))
  datwe[,myCol] <- 
   fn$sqldf("SELECT CASE $myCol
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'No' 
                    WHEN 99 THEN 'NA' 
                    ELSE 'Name ittt' 
                    END as newCol
             FROM datwe")$newCol

#check output, showing only 2 columns
datwe[,23:24]
#    X23 X24
# 1   No Yes
# 2  Yes Yes
# 3  Yes  No
# 4   No  No
# 5  Yes  No
# 6  Yes Yes
# 7   NA  No
# 8   No  No
# 9  Yes  NA
# 10  No  NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and teaching new way of doing it. I will mark it as accepted after hearing some other ways to do(with `sqldf`). I guess I would need to incorporate small change in your solution to make `99` as  `NA`. Thanks !

Comment: Now, I have realized my mistake that all `NA` are stored as `character` values when used `sqldf` statement. Is there any way to convert `NA` character values to `Not Available` ? I guess, I can't use `ifelse()` function on the vector/column as there is only one condition('NA' to NA).

Comment: @Prradep `datwe[,23:37][datwe[,23:37]=="NA"] <- "Not Available"`.

Comment: sorry for my bad communication. I meant `NA`(Not Available) instead of `NA`(character).

Comment: @Prradep `datwe[,23:37][datwe[,23:37]=="NA"] <- NA`, please invest some time and learn [basics of R](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80026/discussion-between-prradep-and-zx8754).